# Nullifying Pointers in Fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran

I am adding a module to a Fortran code, and ran across the following issue. I have a derived data type `Info` that contains several other variables, among them a 4D pointer array (it is a hydro code, so it is 3 spatial components and 1 variable component). To make my subroutine easier to read, I just make a pointer `q` and point to `Info%q`, as follows:

```
    real,pointer::q(:,:,:,:)
    q=>Info%q
    ...
    some work on q
```

The question I am running into is: should I use `deallocate(q)` before `nullify(q)`? Or, since `q` is pointing to an array that is necessary elsewhere in the code, should I just use `nullify`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it is just for readability and your compiler supports it, then use F2003's ASSOCIATE construct instead.  Use of pointers in this case may prevent some optimisations that the compiler would otherwise be able to make.

Comment: I will investigate `associate` further, thank you for the pointer ;) (I really could not help myself with that one, sorry)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only nullify! Otherwise the original pointer would be undefined and the array would no longer exist!

Comment: That is what I thought would happen, but was not 100% positive. Thanks for your help!